# Float not working inside div

Tags: html, css, css-float, styling

May be I am doing some silly mistake causing this issue, but I am stuck.
I need to create 2 adjacent child divs in the parent div. but they are not getting aligned.They come like one down the other. my code is below:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:200px; margin-right:200px; border:2px solid #c5d9eb; background-color: grey">
<div style="margin-left:0px;margin-top=5px;border:2px solid black>
<ul>
<li>Physics</li>
<li>Chemistry</li>
<li>Biology</li>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:80px;margin-top=5px;border:2px solid black>
<ul>
<li>History</li>
<li>Civics</li>
<li>Geography</li>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html
```

and if  I use `float:left` in the `child div`, it moves out of the `parent div`.

Comment: You are missing `"` at the end of your divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `display: table-cell` to make your child div `adjascent`

> Run code snippet below to see the result

```html
<html>
<body>
<div style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:200px; margin-right:200px; border:2px solid #c5d9eb; background-color: grey">
    <div style="margin-left:0px;margin-top=5px;border:2px solid; display: table-cell ">
        <ul>
            <li>Physics</li>
            <li>Chemistry</li>
            <li>Biology</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left:80px;margin-top=5px;border:2px solid black; display: table-cell">
        <ul>
            <li>History</li>
            <li>Civics</li>
            <li>Geography</li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i couldn't understand the behaviour of float. using float throws the child div out of the parent.

Comment: this will help you to understand more about float.. http://designshack.net/articles/css/everything-you-never-knew-about-css-floats/

Comment: pls don't forget to upvote my answer or mark as answer if it helps you. tnx :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your updated code here.

```
<div style="margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 200px; border: 2px solid rgb(197, 217, 235); background-color: grey; margin-left: 200px;">
    <div style="margin-left: 0px; border: 2px solid black; float: left; width: 49%;">
        <ul>
            <li>Physics</li>
            <li>Chemistry</li>
            <li>Biology</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="border: 2px solid black; float: left; width: 49%;">
        <ul>
            <li>History</li>
            <li>Civics</li>
            <li>Geography</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You forgot to add `"` at the end of div style.

 After that give width to both div and `float:left` which give your desirable output.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this still did not work. I ran your code in the browser, but  the child divs are moving out of the parent div with grey background(i gave background color just to understand the code's behaviour). And when I ran the same code without float attribute, it worked fine and gave me the child div inside the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Make child elements `display: inline-block`.

## CSS

```
#parent{
    margin-top:5px; 
    border:2px solid #c5d9eb; 
    background-color: grey
}
#child{
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:5px;
    border:2px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Make parent div `id="parent"`

and both child div `id="child"`